# Trying to SORT table on Expression

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I have two tables in my report. Grouped on fields DatePaidFinancialYear and then SupplierName.

I have removed both sorts on the groups themselves. There is also no sort on the tablix.

I then have a COUNT IF in one table that does the following - 
=Count(IIF(Fields!DaysLateCategory.Value = "Over10Days" , 1, Nothing))
and the below in the other
=Count(IIF(Fields!DaysLateCategory.Value = "Over30Days" , 1, Nothing))

This gives me below -

[image]

I want to sort so that the highest number is at the top. I can't work out how to do it.

When I try and sort by my counts via the Tablix - I get the following error -

***A sort expression for the tablix 'Tablix5' includes an aggregate function.  Aggregate functions cannot be used in data row sort expressions.***

Please advise

Comment: IIRC - you should remove the table sort and sort using the same expression on the **Group** properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IRC - you should remove the table sort and sort using the same expression on the Group properties

Excellent. I could have sworn I tried this but obviously not. All working now.

Thanks